# Bash regex =~ operator match prefix

Tags: bash

Why does this match

```
[[ 'hithere' =~ hi* ]]
```

but this does not

```
[[ 'hithere' =~ *there ]]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be '=~ . *there'?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I imagined it was something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=~` is specifically a [regular expressions operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs). If you want to match zero or more characters, you'll need `.*` instead of just `*`.

```
[[ 'hithere' =~ hi.* ]] && echo "Yes"
Yes

[[ 'hithere' =~ .*there ]] && echo "Yes"
Yes
```

Without anchors, though, the match will succeed even without wildcards.

```
[[ 'hithere' =~ hi ]]
[[ 'hithere' =~ there ]]
# Add anchors to guarantee you're matching the whole phrase.
[[ 'hithere' =~ ^hi.*$ ]]
[[ 'hithere' =~ ^.*there$ ]]
```

For pattern matching, you can use `=` with an unquoted value. This uses [bash pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) instead, which is what you were (evidently) expecting.

```
[[ 'hithere' = hi* ]] && echo "Yes"
Yes

[[ 'hithere' = *there ]] && echo "Yes"
Yes
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps clarify perfectly. I was expecting to use bash pattern matching but instead using the regex operator.

Comment: Note that `[[ hithere =~ *there ]]` has an exit status of 2 (not 1) to indicate that the regular expression was malformed, rather than a simple failure to match.

Comment: You have vicariously helped me add database filtering support to my little mysqldump wrapper, [mysqlbkup](https://github.com/quickshiftin/mysqlbkup), so thank you! Added support for both BASH pattern matching and POSIX Regex ;)

Answer (score 2):

For basic regular expression

preceding `*` is just a character, not considered as special character of regex.

> '*' is an ordinary character if it appears at the beginning of the RE

[Source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

---

Answer by Jeff Bowman works because

`[[ 'hithere' =~ .*there ]] && echo "Yes"` there is a `.` before `*`.